# While Loop Error

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have an assignment to merge two sorted vectors into a third sorted vector.  I'm sure the solution to this problem is pretty simple, but my brain is fried at the moment and could use your help.

Basically vectors A and B have a size of 3. They will hold integers such as 1, 2, 3 and 4, 5, 6 respectively. I can't seem to get the syntax of my while loop correctly. I've tried making it a do/while loop, putting parentheses around the cases, and a few other things. It just doesn't seem to be reading the part after the &&.

The first for loop just makes the R vector have the right size. And the second for loop just displays the values of the R vector. The result should print out from 1-6, but I'm only seeing 1-3.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
void::combine(vector<int> A, vector<int> B, vector<int> R) {
int ia = 0, ib = 0, ir = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < A.size() + B.size(); i++) {
    R.push_back(0);
}

while (ia != A.size() && ib != B.size()) {
        if (A[ia] < B[ib]) {
             R[ir] = A[ia];
             ia += 1;
        }
        else {
            R[ir] = B[ib];
            ib += 1;
        }
        ir += 1;
}

for (int i = 0; i < R.size(); i++) {
    cout << "L3[" << i << "] = " << R[i] << endl;
}

}
```

Comment: Use iterators instead of using size(). Would make your life easier.

Comment: By the way, your goal is not to use that vector afterward, I hope: all the changes you made to `R` are local to the function.

Comment: It would be really nice to know what you're actually trying to accomplish, because basically the if (A[ia] < B[ib]) doesn't really work with the idea of "combining" two vectors in the sense of "concatenation".

Comment: FYI, your assignment is similar to a `merge sort`.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this smells like a classic *merge sort* or a piece of it:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

The objective is to examine elements of the first vector, A, to elements of vector B, and append the elements to a resulting vector R, in order.

Thus if `A[i]` < `B[j]`, append `A[i]` to `R`.  With `std::vector`, there is no need to load the result vector with zeros before starting.  See `std::vector::push_back()`.

The following is untested code:

```
void Sort_Vector(const std::vector& A, const std::vector& B, std::vector& result)
{
  unsigned int index_a = 0;  // Point to first element in first vector.
  unsigned int index_b = 0;  // Point to first element in second vector.
  result.clear();            // Clear all elements, so size == 0.

  while ((index_a < A.size()) && (index_b < B.size())
  {
     if (A[index_a] < B[index_b])
     {
         result.push_back(A[index_a]);
         ++index_a;
     }
     else // B[index_b] <= A[index_a]
     {
         result.push_back(B[index_b]);
         ++index;
     }
  }

  // Append any remaining elements to the result vector.
  // Only one of the two loops should be executed,
  //    the other will fail the comparison expression
  //    and not execute.
  for (; index_a < A.size(); ++index_a)
  {
     result.push_back(A[index_a]);
  }
  for (; index_b < B.size(); ++index_b)
  {
     result.push_back(B[index_b]);
  }
  return;
}
```

Notice the difference between my function's signature (parameters) and yours.  I'm passing the source vectors as constant data and the *result vector is passed by reference* which enables my function to modify the caller's result vector.

Also, I'm lazy and using the `std::vector::push_back()` method.  I believe this is more readable than assigning to an element in the result vector.  The `push_back` method implies that I am appending to the vector.  The assignment route may catch readers off-guard if they forget that a vector will expand in order resolve the assignment.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. I was able to modify my code correctly with your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Assuming A contains [1,2,3] and B contains [4,5,6] as you say, this will not add any of the element in the B vector to the R vector.

This is because on the 4th iteration, ia == 3, and so the conjunctive condition is no longer true..

Try changing it to  `while(ia != A.size() || ib != B.size())`

Comment: This will cause an error however if all the numbers in Vector A are not less than the numbers in Vector B, you may want to re-consider how you've implemented this function

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should avoid the loop altogether:

```
void combine(vector<int> const& A, vector<int> const& B, vector<int> & R) {
   R.resize( A.size() + B.size() );
   std::copy( A.begin(), A.end(), R.begin() );
   std::copy( B.begin(), B.end(), R.begin()+A.size() );
   std::sort( R.begin(), R.end() );
   for ( int i = 0; i < R.size(); ++i )
   {
    cout << "L3[" << i << "] = " << R[i] << endl;
   }
}
```

This is suboptimal as you are first copying and then ordering, but for a small size it will have no impact.

On the actual issues with your code: try to avoid pass-by-value, use resize instead of multiple `push_back()` to fix the size (note that if the `R` argument to your function was a non-empty vector then the final size would be bigger than you want). Consider using a return value instead of a reference argument --easier to read. You looped until the first of the counters reached the end, but left the rest of the elements in the other container without copying.

A manual implementation, using iterators would also be simpler:

```
typedef std::vector<int> vector_t;
vector_t combine( vector_t const & a, vector_t const & b ) {
   vector_t r( a.size() + b.size() ); // [*]
   vector_t::const_iterator ita = a.begin(), enda = a.end();
   vector_t::const_iterator itb = b.begin(), endb = b.end();
   vector_t::iterator itr = r.begin();

   while ( ita != enda && itb != endb ) {
      if ( *ita < *itb )
         *itr++ = *ita++;
      else 
         *itr++ = *itb++;
   }
   if ( ita != enda ) 
      std::copy( ita, enda, itr );
   else 
      std::copy( itb, endb, itr );

   return r;
}
```

Comment: @David: you can use `insert` instead of resizing and then copying,right?

Comment: How is this simpler than e.g. using a for-loop with indices? This looks bloated and it introduces unnecessary complexity.

Comment: If copying first and sorting later isn't optimal, then perhaps a std::set should have been used for the result and not another vector.

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes you can use `push_back` or a `std::back_inserter` iterator adaptor to make it grow as needed. I intended to add that to the answer as I was writing the code (thus the [*]) then I forgot to fill it in :) If the vectors were big, the resize (or `reserve()`) would have the advantage of reducing the reallocations to 1 @Christian: The code (if you remove all the variable declarations) is quite idiomatic in C and C++ and is concise. Granted that the first time that you see the `*x++ = *y++` it will take a couple of seconds reasoning..

Comment: @David: I'm not talking about `push_back` or `back_inserter`. Just `insert`. See my solution!

Comment: @David: Thanks for your response. I could see how your code would make more sense, but this is part of an assignment with specific guidelines, so I'm not really allowed to veer too far off from out material.

Comment: @David Yes, I know that it's a common pattern in C++. My point was more that, for a beginner, this is overwhelming. Iterators, algorithms from the STL, eternal iterator-declarations. It's a correct answer, don't get me wrong. But as a beginner, I'd have been without a clue what this all means ... when I only wanted to write a simple while loop :D

Comment: @Christian: Point taken.  Then again I sometimes wonder whether it does not make sense the approach shown in "Accelerated C++" (which was the textbook for a programming course), where the standard lib, containers and iterators are presented before lower level constructs...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're trying to do in the while loop. But if you're just populating the vector `R` with the elements in `A` and `B`, without giving any regard to the order how they're added, then you can use `insert` function, as:

```
void::combine(const vector<int> &A, const vector<int> &B, vector<int>& R)
{
    R.insert(R.end(), A.begin(), A.end());
    R.insert(R.end(), B.begin(), B.end());
}
```

And if you want to order the vector `R`, then you can add the following line to the above function:

```
 sort( R.begin(), R.end()); //sorts in increasing order.
```

You've to `#include<algorithm>` if you do so. If you want to sort in decreasing order then do this:

```
bool compare( int a, int b ) { return a > b; }
sort( R.begin(), R.end(), compare); //sorts in decreasing order.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Nawaz. Unfortunately, I can't use the sort function because the objective of the assignment is to sort it manually. But yeah R is supposed to contain all the elements of A and B sorted.

Answer (score 0):

that's because of your `&&` condition. as soon as `ia == A.size()`, the first part of the condition `(ia != A.size())` will always evaluate to false and the `ib` part of your loop won't execute.

to fix it, you can change the condition to : `(iA < A.size()) || (iB < B.size())`

Comment: Thats only the conclusssion of the faulty logic in how the loop is built. Changing only the condition will make the program segfault.

Comment: segfault - how? i think the loop will simply exit once the conditional is satisfied.

Comment: because if `iA < A.size()` is satisfied, the whole condition will be satisfied, no matter if `iB < B.size()`, so you will have seg fault, if `iB >= B.size()` and you try to reach the element with index iB (:

Comment: Yeah I tried doing this method earlier. My compiler kept crashing with an assertion error. Like Kiril said, it worked for the ia, but failed when it came to ib

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is fine (the code wouldn't compile otherwise), but your loop condition isn't. Given your example `A = { 1, 2, 3 }` and `B = { 4, 5, 6 }`, the loop will enter the `A[ia] < B[ib]` branch three times and increment `ia` to 3. Once this happens, the first part of the loop condition, `ia != A.size()` won't be true, and so the loop ends.

Since you already know how many items you need to place in the result vector, I'd recommend replacing your `while` loop with a simple `for` one with the same body.

Comment: Yeah I thought about doing that, but I wasn't sure if that would be "allowed" since this is a course assignment. I'll probably use that as a last resort. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

e.g. with 123 and 456 what is being done right now.

1. Initialize `R` to `{0,0,0,0,0,0}`
2. until all values from **one** vector are inserted into `R` compare candidates and insert smaller one into `R`, get next candidate from winner list.

and that's all - I don't know that is the purpose of the function if you'll write it I/We can provide solution otherwise just review 2nd point in above form.